# Unable to unprotect the xlsx, xls files by providing password in ADO (s3 bucket) using java with Aspose workbook

Tags: java, ado

I didn't get any errors or exceptions in ADO using java. I have used Aspose library in java. Please find below code . It didn't throw any errors or exceptions.
I tried alot. I didn't get any solution. It's my first time working on ADO environment.

```
public void removePassword(){
    log.info("****** Entered into  removePassword()*** ");
    try{
        LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions(LoadFormat.XLSX);
        loadOptions.setPassword("XXXX"); 
        if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(isAWS)) {
            File file = awss3Service.loadFileFromS3(rsmAccessEntity.getIfluxawss3bucket(),"dev/sample/upload/22-01-2021/ABCP/" ,"Check_1.xlsx");
            log.info("****** file length*** "+file.length());
            com.aspose.cells.Workbook workbook = new com.aspose.cells.Workbook(new FileInputStream(file),loadOptions);
            workbook.save("Check_1.xlsx", FileFormatType.XLSX);
            File file1 = new File("Check_1.xlsx");
            log.info("****** file1 *** "+file1.length());
            boolean isXlsxProtect = ProtectedFilesUtility.isXlsxProtected(new FileInputStream(file1));
            log.info("****** isXlsxProtect *** "+isXlsxProtect);
            awss3Service.uploadFile(new FileInputStream(file1),"dev/sample/upload/22-01-2021/ABCP/","Check_1.xlsx");    
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.info("****** exception  *** "+e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following line of code to unprotect the encrypted file before Workbook.save() method:

```
workbook.getSettings().setPassword("");
```

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: I tried above approach it's not worked , still file has protected file .i didn't get any exceptions or errors. please find my piece of code..
 com.aspose.cells.Workbook workbook = new com.aspose.cells.Workbook(new FileInputStream(file),loadOptions);
                workbook.getSettings().setPassword("XXXX");
                workbook.save("Check_1.xlsx", FileFormatType.XLSX);